# Separating animations

Tags: animation

Ok, I am using structs to handle my animations. Right now I am unable to animate both my projectile and my character. As soon as I shoot my projectile my character won't move anymore.

I am using the same variables for character starting position and projectile starting position because I need the projectile to start at the character.

I am wondering on how to use the same variables, but separate them, so when the projectile's coordinates are altered... the characters are not.

Comment: Create a new position variable for the projectile and initialize it with the value from the character's position.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using separate variables to store the position of your character and your projectile, and initially setting them to the same value.
The following should be something like what you have now:

```
pos = (0, 0)
def animate():
    pos = add(pos, (1, 1))
```

And the following is an example of using separate variables to store positions; it allows the character to take a path different from the projectile's.

```
characterposition = (0, 0)
projectileposition = (0, 0)
def animate():
    characterposition = add(characterposition, (1, 0))
    projectileposition = add(projectileposition, (1, 1))
```

If you absolutely must use the same variable for both of their positions, you will need to incorporate character and projectile position into that variable separately (i.e. pos = [[0, 0], [0, 0]]).